# can I input a single feature into auto encoder model for anomaly detection?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I used this example from TensorFlow blog to input a single feature to the input layer of autoencoder model:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder

this is the error that I get:
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_2' (type Sequential).

```
    Input 0 of layer "dense_6" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_2' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None


Call arguments received by layer 'anomaly_detector_1' (type AnomalyDetector):
  • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
```

Hi,

I'm new to this.. please excuse my lack of experience and I would really appreciate help if anyone can help me out with what I'm trying to achieve.
I'm trying to use many examples of auto encoder models available on the web.. trying to convert them to my use case.

my data looks like this:
time       vib       anomaly   noise
0.5304  0.028880    1   0.04
0.5305  0.023768    1   0.03
0.5306  0.011101    1   0.01
0.5307  0.028657    1   0.03
0.5308  0.032546    1   0.04
.          .            .          .
2.8882  0.005029    0   0.00
2.8883  0.006252    0   0.00
2.8884  0.005030    0   0.00
2.8885  -0.002301   0   0.00
2.8886  0.002587    0   0.00

I only want to use the vibration column as input and the anomaly column as labels

1)I want to know if I can give a single feature to the input layer and then expand them later on to converge them to an encoded format then apply the decoder layer (if that's how it works?.. from what I understood).

I used this example from TensorFlow blog:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder

It gives me an error stating that the minimum input dimensions must be 2.
I think I need to structure the layers in the right way according to my input.. but I don't know how to.

2)if this is not the way.. please guide me i'm trying to achieve anomaly detection from a single feature input.

3)I'm also willing to use GMM model for anomaly detection. Would that be a better option?

4)My goal is to achieve anomaly detection on streaming sensor data using these models.. Is this the right approach to this?

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thank you.